# Cypress stubbing GET request

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

I'm trying to stub a GET request and so far no luck. Currently the homepage is quite heavy, a hero section with a background video. I want to stub this request for this video so it will just load with an empty string. When I ran the code below, I can see it's trying to get the video frame by frame and as a result it has a risk of timing out. How can I approach this?

```
describe('Homepage', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.app('clean');
    cy.viewport('macbook-13');

    cy.appFactories([
      [
        'create',
        'user',
        {
          id: 1234,
          email: 'john.doe@gmail.com',
          password: 'superSafePassword',
        },
      ],
    ]);
    cy.appScenario('homepage')

    cy.app('feature_flags', ['homepage']);

    cy.server();
    cy.route({
      method: 'GET',     
      url: '/uploads/homepage/video.mp4',   
      response: [],
      status: 200
    });

    cy.visit('/');

  });

  it('shows districts', () => {

    cy.contains('Soho').click({ force: true });

  })
})
```

Comment: Is the video loaded by a XHR request?

Comment: @JosefBiehler yes it is

Comment: ok. It is a bit difficult to do remote debugging here. Maybe you can provide a working application example? or some logs or screenshots. If you want to, you can have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59397185/cypress-xhr-api-call-validation-in-test-cases/59400525#59400525 there I posted a full runnable example